# Windows TFS integration with Azure AD

Tags: windows-server-2003, microsoft-office-365, team-foundation-server, entra-id

One of my client has TFS machine at their on-premises. Now they're planning to configure a machine in Cloud - possibly Azure. So, they already have an existing Office365 business account, where they've emails and user accounts configured. They want to integrate these accounts with TFS, which means they need to be able to login to this TFS portal using their existing office 365 accounts.

As office365 already runs on Azure AD, is it possible to integrate TFS with Azure AD? Microsoft blog says you need to have VSTS to enable this integration, but would be great if anyone can point me to right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the VM in Azure to Azure AD. After joining the VM to Azure AD you can setup the TFS server in that VM and make that accessible to your team.

Steps

1. Setup VM in Azure and make sure to select the virtual network in which your Azure AD Domain Services managed domain is deployed.
2. Join the VM to Azure AD domain services.
3. Setup TFS in the VM and expose it to access from on premises machines.

For more information look at

- [Add machine to Azure AD-DS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm-portal)
- [Administer Azure AD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-administer-domain)

Comment: Thanks for that. But since this setup is new to me, one question:
Since the customer has office365 account, I assume he would have an azure account as well. In that case I can manage this ADDS and create VM's within that azure account and get this done. Am I correct?

Comment: When office 365 is setup Azure AD tenant is automatically provisioned. If it is Azure AD only subscription your client has, you may have to ask them to get a full Azure subscription to create VMs. Some useful information here https://morgansimonsen.com/2014/11/11/manage-azure-active-directory-without-an-azure-subscription-sort-of/